# Use of unresolved identifier 'NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomain'

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to save my pdf in local directory but when I try to run i got

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomain' .

Please help and suggest a better way to save pdf locally if available. Thanks.

My Code is:

```
 func savePdf(){
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomain((.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("documento.pdf"))
    let pdfDoc = NSData(contentsOf:URL(string: documentPathToLoad)!)
    fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: pdfDoc as Data?, attributes: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the trailing `s`

`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`

However there is a better and more contemporary way:

```
func savePdf() throws {
    let documentsURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let pdfDocURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("documento.pdf")
    let pdfData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(string: documentPathToLoad)!)
    try pdfData.write(to: pdfDocURL)
}
```

Note that `URL(string` expects a string path including the scheme like `http://` which is a remote URL in most cases. You are strongly discouraged from using `Data(contentsOf` for a remote URL. If the URL is local you have to use `URL(fileURLWithPath`